# In warden json parameters are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, warden

I am working on rails  json webservices. I am using warden for authentication in that, its working  fine with html format , but in json its not working. because passed parameter is not working in config/intializers/wrden.rb file .below is the code

**config/intializers/warden. rb**

```
def authenticate!

  Rails.logger.info '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
  Rails.logger.info params['emailID']
  user = User.find_by_emailID(params['emailID'])
  if user && user.authenticate(params['password'])
    success! user
  else
    fail "Invalid email or password"
  end

end
```

**here is log of this**

```
Parameters: {"emailID"=>"xyz@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456", "session"=>{"emailID"=>"xyz@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456"}}

(0.2ms)  BEGIN

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

nil

User Load (12.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."emailID" IS **NULL** LIMIT 1

(0.3ms)  COMMIT

Completed   in 276ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just ran into this, too. This GitHub thread fixed it for me:

https://github.com/hassox/warden/issues/84

Basically, tell Warden to use Rails' request object instead of whatever it's using by default. You can use the `rails-warden` gem or mix this into Warden:

```
module Warden::Mixins::Common
    def request
      @request ||= ActionDispatch::Request.new(@env)
    end
end
```